# Can I switch between playback devices without having to restart programs?

Tags: windows-7, audio, playback

I got a pair of USB surround sound headphones. Unlike 3.5mm jack headphones, when these are plugged in they don't "hijack" the audio playback channel; instead I have to manually switch the default playback device by right clicking on the Speakers task bar item.

The problem is changing the default device seems to mess up the sound in all open apps; after switching devices, Chrome and video games will stop outputting sound entirely until they're closed and reopened.

How can I switch output devices without having to restart my apps?